# How to detect addEventlistener when html page is already opened via Iframe in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, postmessage

I want to detect my changes in my ReactApp and want to apply those changes in Html page which is opened via Iframe.

Scenario: I want to use PostMessage handler to update my selected/changed data into my already open html page.

I tried this with "window.postMessage" and "window.AddEventlistener" but my changes are not reflecting here.
What I need to change to make this work. Any suggestion?

//test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

      function receiveMessage(event)
      
      {
        if(event) {
          
          console.log(event.target.value, "hello"); // The idea is too receive the device selected 
        }
        
      }
    </script>
    
</head>
<div>
  <tr>
    Hii
  </tr>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

//ReactApp page

```
  handleSelectDevice(type, event) {

    window.postMessage(JSON.stringify({'data': event.target.value}), "*");

  }
```

//IframeReactjs page

```
class Test extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const testUrl = process.env.PUBLIC_URL+"/test.html";
    return (
      <Iframe id="testid" src={testUrl} width="100%" height={240} />
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the "window" of the iframe, not the main `window` object when calling `postMessage()`.

Considering `ifr` is a variable referencing the iframe element in (HTMLIFrameElement), its window is defined in `ifr.contentWindow`, so the call would be something like

```js
ifr.contentWindow.postMessage(...);
```

More details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

**UPDATE:**
Dummy working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-createref-postmessage-nh881?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hi @zoli thanks for your answer. what this ifr here in my case. Sorry i misunderstood.  I have aded my iframe react component.

Comment: @Tammy See official docs on how to reference DOM elements in React: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Getting error of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of undefined" .

HTMLIFrameElement.contentWindow.postMessage(event, "message", "*" );

Comment: `HTMLIFrameElement` is the type/interface of the `<iframe>` node objects, not something to be directly used. It just defines properties and methods you have access to on actual `<iframe>` elements. You should instead get a reference to the actual `<iframe>` (see link in my previous comment on how to do that) and use that to call `....contentWindow.postMessage()`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook to get the iframe reference, then call `postMessage` function using [HTMLIFrameElement.contentWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow)

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const testUrl = process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/test.html";
    return (
      <Iframe
        ref={this.props.innerRef} //--> pass reference as property
        id="testid"
        src={testUrl}
        width="100%"
        height={240}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Then in app.js

```
 const ref = useRef(null); // reference to iframe

 handleSelectDevice(type, event) {
     // --> postMessage to the iframe
     ref.current.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({'data': event.target.value}), "*");
 }

<Test innerRef={ref}/>
```

Test.html

```
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  console.log(event); // --> listen for messages
});
```

You can get the message data with `event.data`, more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)